# Tree command not found

Tags: operating-system, command

I tried using tree command to see the directory structure but it dint work on my mac terminal, it says : command not found. I tried to install the package for command using $brew install tree. it did not work either???

Answer (score 53):

```
brew install tree
```

Windows and Linux already have the function, so Mac needs installation.

Reference: https://superuser.com/q/359723

Answer (score 39):

Why not make your own? Open up `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` (open that one with `sudo`) and add the following line at the bottom:

```
alias tree='find . -print | sed -e "s;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g"'
```

Now log out and log back in and your `tree` command should work - albeit lacking some function of the utility, no doubt :)

I tested this, but thanks to http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/09/view-folder-tree-terminal-mac-os-tree-equivalent/ for coming up with the idea.

Comment: Adding the alias works but -L to limit levels is not available. I instead used brew install tree.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Homebrew on your Mac, simply use `brew install tree` command on your terminal.

Answer (score 5):

If you dont have availability to install tree in linux, but you have installed gio, you can use `gio tree` with similar functionality.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Linux, try this: sudo apt install tree.

Hope it works.

Comment: In the question: `on my mac terminal`

Comment: At least, it is useful for those who need `tree` in Docker container.

Comment: @Bohdan And running some type of debian. apt is very specific and not really related imo